# Thunar Filemanager hangs

Tags: 16.04, thunar

I'm running ubuntu studio, 16.04, XFCE with Thunar. After some updates this week, the Filemanager hangs for a fair while - over a minute possibly.

When a window does appear, it picks up my network mounted drives but it won't pick up any USB drives.

Running df at the command line also hangs.

Edit: As suggested, I installed another File Manager - Nemo - which exhibited the same problems as Thunar.

I think the problem is with the back-end systems. I'll wait for an update.

Edit 2: And with an update, it's up and running. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is most likely due to low processing power/RAM on your machine. Can you please give specifications of your device? Check the system requirements on the official website and let me know. If it still persists then I would suggest that you reinstall your O.S. and that should fix your problem. Or you can wait for the next update which is much more convenient in my regard.
Edit:    You can install another file explorer from software center or getdeb. If even that doesn't work then re installing or updating might be the only option.

Comment: It was OK last weekend, and it's not OK now. So I'm guessing it's not my machine. I suspect it's the volume manager software which is causing the problems, but the logs are impenetrable.